# problem with jquery addClass function

Tags: jquery, addclass

```
<script>    
$("ul#sol_menu li a").addClass(function()) {
var current_page = document.location.href;
if ($(this).attr.("href").match(current_page)) {
$(this).addClass('highlight');
};
});
</script>
```

What is wrong with this?

Comment: Every single line (but one) has multiple things wrong with it.  You need to learn Javascript syntax and jQuery.

Comment: You know that browsers have an error console, right? `:)`

Comment: @SLaks, which one, the `</script>` line? O.o

Comment: @David: the `var currentPage`

Answer (score 5):

I believe this might be what you were going for...
And as SLaks pointed out, your syntax (in this case) is a bit atrocious...

```
<script>    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var current_page = document.location.href;
        $("ul#sol_menu li a").each(function(){
            if ($(this).attr('href') == current_page) {
                $(this).addClass('highlight');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

So to answer your question... the following was wrong with your code:

1. Depending whether or not your script
   tag was before or after your ul
   element, you need to use the
   $(document).ready function
2. You weren't using the addClass callback properly...
3. You had an extra bracket at the addClass callback "addClass(function()) {" should have been "addClass(function() {"
4. There's no .match method like the one you've used...
5. You had a syntax error here:
   '.attr.("href")'; no period after
   '.attr'


   Hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you're trying to do, with comments so hopefully you learn something about Javascript/jQuery:

```
// when DOM is ready
$(function(){    

    // cache current URL
    var current_page = document.location.href;

    // use .each method to check link hrefs against current location
    $("ul#sol_menu li a").each(function () {

        // if this link is for the current page, highlight it
        if (current_page.indexOf(this.href) >= 0) {
            $(this).addClass('highlight');
        };

    });

});
```